# Wifi connection and routing unstable. Ethernet works fine

Tags: networking, wireless, dell, iwlwifi, xps

The router is configured on `192.168.1.1`. When the ethernet cable is plugged in I can see the router's homepage and all internet browsing is fine.

When using the wifi only the connection to the routers homepage is very slow as is intermittent access to certain APIs and websites. The browser/curl can resolve the routers homepage but there is little to no connectivity.

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enx00e111002949
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enx00e111002949
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0
```

```
uname -a
Linux xyz 5.4.0-42-generic #46~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 07:21:24 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The wifi device is

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 2723 (rev 1a)
```

and using the latest drivers for https://www.killernetworking.com/products/killer-ax1650/

EDIT:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
[    4.957222] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[    4.957223] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8324:9176b151
[    5.260806] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    5.276799] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-dbg-cfg.ini failed with error -2
[    5.278797] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    5.278824] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.22
[    5.278830] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    5.278833] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    5.279273] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 55.d9698065.0 cc-a0-55.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.279514] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[    5.437971] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    5.643259] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: 04:ed:33:c0:5a:9e
[    5.729155] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
```

```
modinfo iwlwifi
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/updates/dkms/iwlwifi.ko
version:        iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8324:9176b151
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-gf-a0-55.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-gf4-a0-55.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-55.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-55.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-55.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-jf-b0-55.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-cc-a0-55.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-jf-b0-55.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-55.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-55.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-55.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-55.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-hr-b0-55.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-jf-b0-55.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-hr-a0-55.ucode
...
depends:        compat,cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
name:           iwlwifi
vermagic:       5.4.0-42-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           debug:debug output mask (uint)
parm:           xvt_default_mode:xVT is the default operation mode (default: false) (bool)
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 2K for AX210 devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K 4: 2K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           enable_ini:Enable debug INI TLV FW debug infrastructure (default: true (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_11ax:Disable HE capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_msix:Disable MSI-X and use MSI instead (default: false) (bool)
parm:           remove_when_gone:Remove dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible (default: false) (bool)
```

Resolve

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

When the wifi is connected via tethering to a mobile network all activity is normal using the same wifi device, this makes me suspect that it is not related to the wifi driver.

when the routers UI is accessed with Ethernet or **another** macbook it works fine and there are no connectivity issues.

For some reason there are timeouts and internet stalls only when using the wifi. Pages connect and then fail to load. API calls via tools gcloud etc timeout.

It works fine in windows.

Is there something wrong with the DNS? Routing or something else that can be investigated?

How can I try and find the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

Switching back to 5.3.0-62-generic and it all works fine. Seems the drivers have an issue with 5.4+ kernel versions